# Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object with

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in line 217

```
Line 217:   <a href="'. (!$is_placeholder?$image[0]:'javascript:void(0);') . '" ' . (!$is_placeholder?' rel="prettyPhoto"':'') . '><img src="'. $image[0] . '" title="' . $value->post_title . '" style="height:80px;width:80px;"/></a>
```

Its been many years since I was a developer, so please don't be mean, I need a hand with this.
This is wordpress 5.3.2 with woocommerce 4.0. Php 7.2 with cpanel in centOS

Comment: Can you show full source code? It seems like $value is not object array. Try with get_the_title();

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your $value variable is not an instance of [WP_Post](http://dfile:///Users/grafica1/Library/Application%20Support/Dash/DocSets/WordPress/WordPress.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/index.html).

If your code is inside the WP loop or in a single post or page, you can use `get_the_title()` instead of `$value->post_title`.

Else, you have to set the variable with the post, like this:

```php
<?php $value = get_post(100); // change '100' with the right post ID ?>
<a href="'. (!$is_placeholder?$image[0]:'javascript:void(0);') . '" ' . (!$is_placeholder?' rel="prettyPhoto"':'') . '><img src="'. $image[0] . '" title="' . $value->post_title . '" style="height:80px;width:80px;"/></a>
```